# The multi-part identifier could not be found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql code here. I am trying to left join two tables and where there is no match I want to change the status code for the first table to be changed.

```
Update pbmsys.dbo.mhj_tmp_list 
SET 
    a.status_cd = 'I'
FROM 
   pbmsys.dbo.mhj_tmp_list a 
LEFT JOIN 
    staging.dbo.delity_List1 b
ON 
  a.drug_id = b.drug_id 
where 
   a.mac_id = 154 and b.drug_id is null
```

I am getting an error

> "The multi-part identifier "a.status_cd" could not be bound."

The column is in the table. How do i fix this? am I writing an incorrect code for what I am trying to achieve here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
Update pbmsys.dbo.mhj_tmp_list 
SET 
    a.status_cd = 'I'
FROM 
   pbmsys.dbo.mhj_tmp_list a 
LEFT JOIN 
    staging.dbo.delity_List1 b
ON 
  a.drug_id = b.drug_id 
where 
   a.mac_id = 154 and b.drug_id is null
```

You should have:

```
Update a --<-- this is the alias of the table pbmsys.dbo.mhj_tmp_list
SET 
    a.status_cd = 'I'
FROM 
   pbmsys.dbo.mhj_tmp_list a --<-- this is the alias of the table pbmsys.dbo.mhj_tmp_list
LEFT JOIN 
    staging.dbo.delity_List1 b
ON 
  a.drug_id = b.drug_id 
where 
   a.mac_id = 154 and b.drug_id is null
```

The reason for the error is you have given the table `pbmsys.dbo.mhj_tmp_list` the alias `a` in the `FROM` part of the `UPDATE` and the column you are updating is `a.status_cd` however in the `UPDATE` section you have `pbmsys.dbo.mhj_tmp_list` rather than the alias `a`